# Docker says “Docker hv-sock proxy (vsudd) is not reachable”

Tags: windows, docker

Docker says “Docker hv-sock proxy (vsudd) is not reachable”.
Why?

I saw valid work of docker only after clean Windows

and Docker installation.

It is failed, fixed and failed again after that.

```
netcfg -d
```

could not help me now, but helped before.

I also tried to switch to other Windows containers

and back to Linux without success.

**The problem is only on Linux containers
using Windows OS.**

(Windows 10 x64 1709, VT on.)

HELP!!! Please!

Comment: Did you find the fix to this problem?